# Is there a way to run Linux inside Windows 10 that does not require Virtualbox or any other Virtual Machine

Tags: windows-10, linux-distributions

Is there a way to run Linux inside Windows 10 which does not require Virtualbox or any other Virtual Machine?

- So I can install it in a folder or in one of my hard drive partitions?
- So it can run while Windows is also running (no need to boot or restart, etc.)

Comment: You can always just [run Linux in your browser](http://bellard.org/jslinux/index.html).

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is wrong to use VM? It fulfill your requirement ( install in a folder, run while Windows is also running) ?

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/

Answer (score 1):

There is a version of Linux that will run in **32 bit** Windows OSs.  It is called [Andlinux](http://www.andlinux.org/).  I have not tried it myself, but have read articles that state it does work.

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin Shell (https://www.cygwin.com/) is a linux emulator that runs inside Windows.

Comment: While this is surely the best answer that can be found within the narrow confines of the OP, it should be pointed out that the HomePage of the Cygwin project states that: **Cygwin is not a way to run native Linux apps on Windows nor a way to magically make native Windows apps aware of UNIX® functionality like signals, ptys, etc**

Comment: @MariusMatutiae But most Linux apps will work in Cygwin, unless they require a desktop environment

Comment: Cygwin is not an emulator.  It provides a UNIX like environment for Windows.

Comment: @geek1011 Linux apps will ***not*** work in Cygwin.  They have to be compiled from source to run in Cygwin on Windows.

Comment: @Keltari I mean Cygwin versions of most Linux apps are available.

Answer (score -2):

Deepin can be istalled without the need to create a partition for it or a medium such as a USB drive to run it from (although it can be installed that way as well). Just download the ISO, right-click and select "Mount", and open the DEEPIN_S.exe file. It's no different than installing a program and it will not overwrite the Windows bootloader with a GRUB bootloader. Instead when you boot your computer the Windows bootloader will give you the option to choose which OS you want to use.
The installer will simply ask you to create a username, password, and select how much hard drive space you want to use for Deepin. 20GB is the default/minimum.
As it will instruct you, it is important to go to Control Panel>All Control Panel Items>Power Options>System Settings, select "Change settings that are currently unavailable" and turn OFF fast startup. If you don't do this before reboot the installation will fail. Once your computer has rebooted and the installation has completed you can turn it back on.

Note: These instructions should apply to most if not all versions of Windows currently being used. The only difference might be the fast startup settings. Also, Deepin is a beautiful OS and very user-friendly, but also a bit power hungry. If your experience any lagging go to the Display settings and set the Windows Effects setting to "Off". This will greatly improve system performance on slower machines.
If at any time you want to uninstall Deepin just login to Windows, go to the root of your Windows drive (usually C:), open the Deepin folder and run the uninstall.exe file. Then delete the Deepin folder along with the uninstaller.

Comment: "So it can run while Windows is also running (no need to boot or restart, etc.)"

Answer (score -3):

you can use lick software(git hub) and puppy Linux to run Linux inside of windows 10 (if you have 32 bit win7 or old then try wubi(ubuntu) and other potable Ubuntu
but win10 does not support it.so I recommend you to install lick and puppy os latest xenial distro. if you want other Linux distro then you have to use virtual box. you can now use Linux as windows subsystem but only support CLI but you can also use GUI app from it but I don't recommend it.

if you are android fan then install android x86 on usb (you need two usb ine for boot and another for installation(best alternative).